# numbering theorem in sections of an article

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am writing an article in WinEdt (Windows 7), but it's creating problem in numbering the theorems in subsections. My article consists of different sections. In section 3 it starts with a Lemma and by the `\begin{lemma}` command it takes the number "Lemma 3.1", which is as desired. But next when I declare `\begin{theorem}` then it takes the number "Theorem 3.2", which should be "Theorem 3.1". Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  how theorem-like objects are numbered depends on how they are defined (in the preamble of your document), which in turn depends on the theorem package and/or the document class being used.  you haven't identified either, so we don't have enough information to go on.  what would be most helpful is a "minimum example", beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that can be cut-and-pasted for experimentation.

Comment: What are you getting is more natural (better) than what you want, (theorems, lemma, corollary) should be numbered in continous way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `amsmath` package, the default is for each newtheorem to be numbered separately. In your preamble, you should see something like

`\newtheorem{ABC}{DEF}[GHI]`

The ABC is the codename you use in the `\begin` command; and DEF is what is displayed (e.g. "Lemma"). GHI says how they should be numbered (chapter/section/subsection, etc.).

If the lemmas and theorems are numbered together, then your preamble probably looks like

`\newtheorem{JKL}[MNO]{PQR}`

In this case, JKL is the codename as before, PQR is the display name as before. However, MNO is a reference for another theorem environment that specifies that JKL and MNO should be numbered together (so in your example lemma has MNO=theorem; or theorem has MNO=lemma; or both has MNO=some other environment).

I hope this helps =)

Comment: You could significantly improve this answer by showing a full example and a screen shot